# Start week from monday JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the calendar taken from https://github.com/500tech/angular-simple-calendar.

In this calendar the week starts from sunday and is calculated in this function :

```
  calculateWeeks = function () {
    $scope.weeks = [];
    var week = null;
    var daysInCurrentMonth = new Date($scope.selectedYear, MONTHS.indexOf($scope.selectedMonth) + 1, 0).getDate();
    for (var day = 1; day < daysInCurrentMonth + 1; day += 1) {
      var dayNumber = new Date($scope.selectedYear, MONTHS.indexOf($scope.selectedMonth), day).getDay();
      week = week || [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
      week[dayNumber] = {
        year: $scope.selectedYear,
        month: MONTHS.indexOf($scope.selectedMonth),
        day: day
      };

      if (allowedDate(week[dayNumber])) {
        if ($scope.events) { bindEvent(week[dayNumber]); }
      } else {
        week[dayNumber].disabled = true;
      }

      if (dayNumber === 6 || day === daysInCurrentMonth) {
        $scope.weeks.push(week);
        week = undefined;
      }
    }
  };
```

What changes I should do to start week from Monday?

Comment: `dayNumber = (dayNumber || 7) - 1;` should do it, right after the `var dayNumber` line.

Comment: this worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could change the definition of `dayNumber` by adding 6 modulo 7:

```
var dayNumber = (new Date($scope.selectedYear, MONTHS.indexOf($scope.selectedMonth), day)
                .getDay() + 6) % 7;
```